# How to make C++ #define statement doesn't wrap after VScode formatting?

Tags: c++, format, visual-studio-code

When I write C++ code in Visual Studio Code after automatically formatting, it will be

```cpp
#define IOS                      \
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false); \
    cin.tie(0);                  \
    cout.tie(0);
#define printvec(vec) \
    for (auto e : vec) cout << e << " ";
```

Instead I want to do like:

```cpp
#define IOS ios::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
#define printvec(vec) for(auto e:vec) cout<<e<<" ";
```

How do I do that?

I’ve already installed the C/C++ extension from the marketplace.

Comment: Change the line width style rules.

Comment: O.T.: Why do you intend to write such macros? It looks like these terrible things which seem to belong to the culture of competitive programming sites but are still bad C++ style (in the rest of the world). (As if functions where not yet invented...)

Comment: O.T.: If I write macros (which I try to prevent but sometimes I just have no better idea), I write them in a way that they can be used like statements. E.g. leave the last `;` out or even wrap statements into something which makes them usable as a single statement like e.g. `#define DO_SOMETHING do { /* multiple statements */ } while (false)`. So, the macro code wouldn't even break if used e.g. in an `if (cond) DO_SOMETHING; else { /* do something else */ }`

Comment: @Scheff Thank you very much for your valuable advice, I learned a lot from it. In addition, as you said, the code in the question is only used to improve coding efficiency in algorithm competitions.

Comment: @M.A Thanks for your answer. I set `{BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0, AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: true, AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true}` in `Clang_format_fallback Style` property. And set the `word wrap` property to false. But it seems to have no effect.

Comment: There's an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36797) to disable formatting on some particular code blocks

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for your answer. This issue is about TypeScript, it seems that there is no effective solution for C++.